# Google Chrome display json AJAX response as tree and not as a plain text, new verison

Tags: json, google-chrome, networking, preview

In my google chrome browser version 61.0.3163.100 (official build) (64 bits)
shows ajax json requests in string format and not as a tree. in the Network Preview tab. what may be the problem, I need some help

Answer (score 0):

I tried the developer edition and it still had the same issue, so I reverted back to a previous version.

Reverting back to 60.0.3112.113 seems to be the best option at this point.

My system is OSX - not sure if you are in the same boat as me.

Some links for Windows to re-download: https://community.webroot.com/t5/Security-Industry-News/Google-Chrome-60-0-3112-113-Stable/td-p/299760

Hope this helps!

Comment: my operating system is windows. Apparently the best option is to return an earlier version, until you solve the problem.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help! It sure made debugging some of my code hard without it.